# For the recent approval of pilegesh in the circumstance of a married man unable to procreate, is kiddushin required?

Tags: halacha, marriage

[Recently a Rabbinical Court in Jerusalem approvied a pilgesh in certain situations where a man cannot reproduce with his wife.](http://mostlykosher.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/rabbinical-court-approved-concubine.html)

The Vilna Gaon and others (including Jerusalem Talmud, possibly Bavli with other girsa?) prohibit pilegesh without Kiddushin. Does this court approve of pilegesh with or without kiddushin?

Comment: What does it mean when it says that the wife "refuses to grant her husband a divorce". I did not think a divorce was granted by the wife.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok just guessing, but perhaps she refuses to accept it somehow